# Inverting colours HTML5 canvas tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

So this website http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-invert-image-colors-tutorial/ has a tutorial for inverting colours. I have been trying to do something similar and it doesn't work, although I have no errors. Also I am running it on a local server cause I originally came across the security error which stopped it running properly and now Chrome has no issue running through the code. I just don't see any change on screen.
I decided to transfer their code into JSFiddle just to see it work and then learn by changing values, but the darth vader image isn't inverted when I hit run. Does this mean that their example code is missing something and would explain why I don't see any change with what I'm working on?

Thanks for any help.

As requested http://jsfiddle.net/user69247/fMwp5/1/

(Sorry it wanted the code posted as well because I have jsfiddle link)

```
<html>
  <head>
   <style>
     body {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
  }
</style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="400"></canvas>
    <script>
      function drawImage(imageObj) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var x = 69;
    var y = 50;

    context.drawImage(imageObj, x, y);

    var imageData = context.getImageData(x, y, imageObj.width, imageObj.height);
    var data = imageData.data;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
      // red
      data[i] = 255 - data[i];
      // green
      data[i + 1] = 255 - data[i + 1];
      // blue
      data[i + 2] = 255 - data[i + 2];
    }

    // overwrite original image
    context.putImageData(imageData, x, y);
  }

  var imageObj = new Image();
  imageObj.onload = function() {
    drawImage(this);
  };
  imageObj.src = 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide the fiddle that you've created - we can look and see what's awry then.

Comment: Sorry should have done that to begin with, added it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use a locally hosted image - or a data url.  The error I got in the fiddle was that there was a cross-browser issue.  The following modified fiddle works OK.

```
image.src = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBOR....seefiddle'
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fMwp5/2/

Comment: Oh right, so it is basically like the issue I had before with my code before setting up MAMP. This gives me something to go on at least in working out what I'm doing doesn't quite work. Thanks